# Jtextpane string editor

Tags: java

Can somebody give me a code to make some strings not editable( not removable) in a jtexpane please?
I saw that i have to use a document filter to do it. Is there any other way to achieve this? If not please give me some sample codes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A clear elaboration of what project you are working on will be necessary. Anyways, if you can switch to JTextArea instead of JTextPane, you can have a look at [Make parts of a JTextArea non editable (not the whole JTextArea!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030477/make-parts-of-a-jtextarea-non-editable-not-the-whole-jtextarea)

If this helps you or you have a query do reply.